# Hide Start Orb on Vista / Win 7 in C#

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-vista, taskbar

When hiding the Task Bar on Vista and Windows 7 the Start Button (also known as the Start Orb) doesn't get hidden. I've been looking for a solution to this and I've found one but it seems more complex than necessary.
This [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/hide_vista_start_orb.aspx) describes (and contains code for) a solution where you enumerate all child windows of all threads in the process that contains the start menu.

Has anyone found a simpler solution?

Just for reference. The code for hiding the Task Bar (without hiding the Orb) is as follows. First do the necessary Win32 imports and declarations.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowText);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int command);


private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
private const int SW_SHOW = 1;
```

Then, in a method somewhere, call them with the right arguments

```
IntPtr hwndTaskBar = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
ShowWindow(this.hwndTaskBar, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: I think this is somewhat of a duplicate question.  Someone already posted asking how to hide the taskbar and the solution given is to have the form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;  This combo should hide the taskbar quite well.  I have no problem doing this on Win7.  Didn't try it on Vista.

Comment: That doesn't hide the Task Bar. It covers it up.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen

Comment: Ah... you want it to go away altogehter? :)

Comment: Yes. I don't have the luxury of covering the entire screen with a single window.

Comment: You can create a secondary window that covers the screen, and then let your other windows do whatever they like. Don't run around hiding the taskbar manually -- what if two programs did that? Or what if your program crashes before it gets a chance to unhide it?

Comment: @RaymondChen Program crash before unhiding is definitely a problem with this approach. Perhaps you can help to get a cleaner way to accomplish this included in the OS? As I indicated in the comment directly above yours, I don't have the luxury of covering the entire screen with a single window.

Comment: Creating a fullscreen window is the only option. Can't you just spin off a worker thread to create a dummy fullscreen window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to put together a solution that didn't require all the thread enumeration. Here are the relevant parts.

If you declare `FindWindowEx` as follows

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(
       IntPtr parentHwnd,
       IntPtr childAfterHwnd,
       IntPtr className,
       string windowText);
```

You can then access the window handle for the Start Orb like this:

```
IntPtr hwndOrb = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)0xC017, null);
```

and disable the Start Orb like this:

```
ShowWindow(hwndOrb, SW_HIDE);
```

The key to this method is that we use the `IntPtr` type for the className variable instead of a string in the `FindWindowEx` function. This allows us to use the portion of this function that takes an `ATOM` type rather than a `string`. I was able to discern that the particular `ATOM` to use is at `0xC017` from this post:
[Hide Vista Start Orb](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/0c129cb1-ca14-4991-b76e-f80ee308dd87)

Hope this simplified version helps some people.

UPDATE:
I created this new [Code Project Page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Hide_Vista_Start_Orb_Simp.aspx) to document this process.