# how to detect a right-to-left windows interface c#?

Tags: windows, c#, interface

i want to place a small form above the notification icons 
in left-to-right interface the icons to the right of the screen
in right-to-left interface the icons to the left of the screen
i want the code for that to work on xp and win7 please

Comment: You'll have better luck with something like this on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
private static bool IsRightToLeft()
{
     return CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The flag you're looking for is `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` (400000 hexadecimal). You get this flag by calling `GetWindowLong(FindWindow(L"HHTaskBar", NULL), GWL_EXSTYLE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Any `System.Windows.Forms.Control` support such check: `Control.RightToLeft`.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft.aspx)

Comment: It's actually an underlying property of all windows, and you don't want it from a random window. You want the RTL proeprty from the taskbar window.

Answer (score 0):

Stuart Dunkeld
that dosnt help , CultureInfo has nothing to do with the interface
if i could locate the location of the start button (on the taskbar) that would help

Answer (score 0):

If you insist you can find the position and size of the Windows start button.
To do that, first add this inside your class:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rectangle rectangle);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, IntPtr className, string lpszWindow);
```

Then use such code.. in this example I show its width but you can read its Left/Right location as well:

```
IntPtr hwndTaskBarWin = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell_TrayWnd", null);
IntPtr hwndStartButton = FindWindowEx(hwndTaskBarWin, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", null);
if (hwndStartButton.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    //Maybe Vista/Windows7?
    hwndStartButton = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)0xC017, null);
}

if (hwndStartButton.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, can't find the Start button/orb");
}
else
{
    Rectangle rect = Rectangle.Empty;
    if (GetWindowRect(hwndStartButton, ref rect))
        MessageBox.Show("Start button width: " + rect.Width);
}
```

Tested successfully under XP and Windows7, the Vista/7 trick credit goes to Waylon Flynn in his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165879/hide-start-orb-on-vista-win-7-in-c).