# Convert C# P/Invoke code to Python ctypes?

Tags: python, windows-7, ctypes

I'm having problem converting this C# code to python using ctypes. This code is for hiding windows 7 start orb. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165879/hide-start-orb-on-vista-win-7-in-c-sharp).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(
       IntPtr parentHwnd,
       IntPtr childAfterHwnd,
       IntPtr className,
       string windowText);

IntPtr hwndOrb = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)0xC017, null);
```

do i have to define

```
FindWindow = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowEx
FindWindow.restype = wintypes.HWND
FindWindow.argtypes = [
    wintypes.HWND, ##hWnd
    wintypes.HWND, ##hWnd
]
```

Or just use it directly? Sorry I'm new in using python ctypes.

```
hWnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx (win32gui.GetDesktopWindow(),
None,0xC017 ,None)
```

Comment: Have you possibly considered using `IronPython` which should provide more convenient access to the .NET framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be helpful to have the error message you're seeing. However, this is almost certainly because you need to use `user32.FindWindowExW` (or `user32.FindWindowExA` if you really want the ASCII, non-Unicode version) rather than straight FindWindowEx. You also need to specify argtypes for all four parameters.

Here's the prototype from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
HWND WINAPI FindWindowEx(
  _In_opt_  HWND hwndParent,
  _In_opt_  HWND hwndChildAfter,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpszClass,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpszWindow
);
```

So what about this?

```
FindWindowEx = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowExW
FindWindowEx.argtypes = [
    wintypes.HWND,
    wintypes.HWND,
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,
]
FindWindowEx.restype = wintypes.HWND
```

You can also do FindWindow (rather than FindWindowEx) as per the C# code you linked to:

```
>>> FindWindow = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW
>>> FindWindow.argtypes = [wintypes.LPCWSTR, wintypes.LPCWSTR]
>>> FindWindow.restype = wintypes.HWND
>>> FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', '')
65670L
```

Comment: Also note: yes, unless it's a function just taking an int, you'll need to define the restype/argtypes explicitly like this. Otherwise it won't work correctly between 32-bit and 64-bit code with pointer types. See also [my post about this here](http://tech.oyster.com/cherrypy-ctypes-and-being-explicit/).

Comment: thanks @Ben Hoyt for sample code. But how can i make FindWindowEx accept (IntPtr)0xC017? What wintypes or ctypes will be used?

Comment: Oh, I see: `FindWindowEx()` has a very strange double-use of that third argument -- it can be either a string or an int. I guess in this case you'd use `ctypes.cast(0xC017, wintypes.LPCWSTR)`. If you're using it with ints often, define the argtypes with a correctly-sized integer instead of an LPCWSTR.