# Hide Start Menu and Start Button in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm setting my console full screen but I also want to hide the task bar and the start button in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2010

Thanks

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1165879/62576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of hiding the taskbar is by ending the explorer process.

```
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
    If p.ProcessName = "explore" Then
       p.Kill()
    End If
Next
```

When you're finished you'll have to restart the explorer process.

```
Process.Start("explorer")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended using Sam solution, but I did another way as using Process.Kill didn't prevent explorer.exe to restart automatically.

Had to use taskkill this way:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("taskkill.exe", " /f /im explorer.exe")
```

Then when you close your application you call explorer.exe again:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Windows\explorer.exe")
```

I had to use the full path because calling "explorer.exe" didn't restore the task bar.