# How to bring Windows Taskbar on foreground while running maximized?

Tags: c#, .net, fullscreen, taskbar

I've got an app running maximized in a borderless window and need access to the windows taskbar on a given user event.

How would I bring the taskbar in foreground in .NET while running maximized?

Also an hint with regards to how to make it reliably go away wouldn't hurt! :)

**EDIT**: please note that I don't want the taskbar always on, I want it popping up on foreground just on a given user event, and then I want it to go away at will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, your desired solution seems to be the problem that caused [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen/507562#507562). See my answer there. You may have to experiment a little with setting the FormBorderStyle and WindowState properties in a certain order, and try to minimize disturbance for the user.

Comment: thanks - note that I don't want the taskbar always on, I awant it on foreground jsut on a given user event, and then I want to send it away! :)

Comment: thanks to your answer on the other question I realized that (with a maximized app): 1) if the taskbar is locked framing the window with SingleBorder bring sup the taskbar (my taskbar was set to auto-hide) 2) once the task bar is up removing the SingleBorder won't make it go away unless I minimize then maximize again.

Answer (score 2):

Um, don't run fullscreen? Maybe run maximized? Fullscreen app with taskbar is not a standard UI pattern.

What you could try doing is run maximized without the UI chrome (borderless window).  Would let the taskbar in on the fun while still looking like a fullscreen app.

Comment: Sorry this is already my scenario - I will rephrase the original post - How would I bring the taskbar on foreground on a maximized app so?

Comment: Well, hell...  you're talking about taskbars that are set to auto-minimize?  Never done that.  Seems like a p/invoke situation.  Check this out http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/01/26/CSharp-Flash-Window-in-Taskbar-via-Win32-FlashWindowEx.aspx might work by flashing the icon on the task bar.