# How to maximise a Windows 10 Universal Application's window to full screen when running on a desktop?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-10

When building a universal application using Windows 10 (or Windows 8.1 WinRT), is it possible to force the application's main window to maximise on launch? This is obviously natural behaviour for the application when running on a mobile device but not when running on the desktop.

This is certainly possible using WinForms:

- [How do I make a WinForms app go Full Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen)
- [How to display a Windows Form in full screen on top of the taskbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272019/how-to-display-a-windows-form-in-full-screen-on-top-of-the-taskbar)

But I haven't so far managed to find anything in the Microsoft Documentation about this for Windows 10.

Comment: As a user, I don't think I wish an application to be able to do this....

Comment: @IanRingrose I completely agree. However, in this instance the application that I'm creating appears very briefly and is for a very niche instance of face detection. It's a rare example where this might actually need to happen.

Comment: I don't know if such a feature will be available in windows 10. But in windows 8.1 I don't think it's possible. The user is the one who chooses if the application is snapped or not

Comment: I've not tried yet, but this may be help for you:
[ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode | tryEnterFullScreenMode method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryenterfullscreenmode.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An app can request to start as full screen by setting the ApplicationView.[PreferredLaunchWindowingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchwindowingmode.aspx) to [ApplicationViewWindowingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewwindowingmode.aspx).FullScreen

Roberth discussed this along with other view and window size issues in his Build session [Navigation and Windowing in Universal Windows Apps](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-779)

Comment: Is there an option to somehow hint Windows to run Windows 8.1 store app to run fullscreen on Windows 10? Since this API is only available for Windows 10 apps and we have existing 8.1 app that we would like to run fullscreen by default without having to worry about 'porting' it to Windows 10.