# Switch running WinStore App to fullscreen

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In Windows 8 Win Store apps started by default in full screen mode.

In Windows 10 Desktop Mode apps starts in windowed mode, and app title bar has additional icon, which allows to switch to full screen mode (first icon, note that it's different behavior than maximizing window, third icon).

[image: Windows 10 Win Store Title Bar]

Is there a possibility to maximize this window programatically, e.g. via WinAPI call? Alternatively, is there any option (other than switching to Tablet Mode) to start it in full screen by default?

Question is ***not*** about changing app sources, I want to switch running app to full screen as a part of automated testing process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maximise a Windows 10 Universal Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936104/how-to-maximise-a-windows-10-universal-applications-window-to-full-screen-when)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can *try* to make the app runs in full screen by:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

And try to play and check the methods available in `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView()`.. You'll love it :)

Comment: Can I access correct `ApplicationView` object outside of app sources?

Comment: No you can't.. your call has to be inside your application.

Comment: _Question is not about changing app sources, I want to switch running app to full screen as a part of automated testing process._