# how to do Monitor fit application in winform?

Tags: winforms

In my winform application want to cover full computer monitor. But, windows 7 task bar visible.

how to code Monitor fit application in winform?

[image: see statusStrip1]

thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its already answered here

[How do I make a WinForms app go Full Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen)

Comment: no no,.. It doesn't help me... They say change property,. but i already done that. till now the task bar in top.

Answer (score 1):

In the Shown event handler add the following code:

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
Bounds = Screen.GetBounds(this);
```

Comment: NO USE. STILL NOW THE TASKBAR NOT HIDE!

Answer (score 1):

Try these lines of code in `Form_Load`

`Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

TopMost = true;

MaximizeBox = false;`

Comment: @Sagotharan: I have tried this and this works! Can you describe, in what way it is misbehaving?

Comment: Are you got the full screen?. Amazing. The same thing, taskbar not hide. I am using Windows 7 and visual studio 2011.

Comment: @Sagotharan: Where on earth you have got VS2011 from? I have tested this on Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. It just works out of the box. These very lines of code are sufficient to achieve what you have asked as a question!

Comment: OH VERY SORRY FOR VERSION MISTAKE.

Answer (score 1):

set property of form to

```
form1.windowstate= maximized;
```

it will solve your