# C# - Graphics drawing and taskbar

Tags: c#, screenshot

I`m need to draw a rectangle over all windows.
For this, I am using a topmost and fullscreen form, and System.Drawing.Graphics.
The problem is that the rectangle is created via DrawRectangle does not cover the taskbar. at the screenshot right rectangle is drawn as follows:

```
g.DrawRectangle (MyPen, 300, 300, 800, 1000);
g.FillRectangle (brGradient, 300, 300, 800, 1000);
```

but apparently, it does not cover the taskbar, although it is covered by the form (the cursor on the panel is the same as in the whole form, rather than the standard arrow). In what may be the problem?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen

Comment: I saw this question, but it doesnt works for me.

Comment: It does for me. What OS are you using? Have you tried starting a new app and testing the sample? I used the exact code from the link above and changed the BackColor to black with an opacity of 50% and it looked just like what I'd expect.

Comment: Windows 7 x32. In my program the taskbar is 50% transparent too. Problem is with rectangle.