# Fullscreen application option (hide app title bar)

Tags: c#, winforms, titlebar

Hello I would like to know if there is a way to have my application run, without a title bar, essentially maximized so that only the body is visible on the screen. I'm sure I can work things like a show/hide option for a `menuStrip` on `mouseOver` or something like that, but for the title bar, I'm not sure. If there was a way to show/hide that on a `mouseOver` can someone provide an example? This is for a WinForms application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a WinForms app go Full Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WinForms, you can just set `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want something easy you should work on a panel instead of work directly on the form and set the panel's dock to fill. So:

```
//...
panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

//some stuff here

Controls.Add(panel);
```

Then when you want to see the full screen application, maximize the form and hide the titlebar like here:

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```