# Borderless application on maximize is hiding behind the task bar in Win 7 and Win 8

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a borderless window in WPF. I have written a event to maximize the window but on maximizing, part of the window sometimes hides behind the task bar and after a moment appears on top of the task bar.

How can I ensure that the window remains on top of task bar every time ? Following is the way I have implemented:

```
private void OnMaximizedClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = this.WindowState != WindowState.Normal ? WindowState.Normal : WindowState.Maximized;
}
```

I have tried setting the TopMost property to true, but didn't help me either.

Comment: How do you maximize a window in a "windowless application"?

Comment: I am creating a stackpanel on the grid, adding three buttons, min, max and close. In other words creating my own title bar.

Comment: It's called "borderless window".  I don't repro this behavior.

Comment: On continuous maximizing and restoring the window, I can see this behaviour. Properties which I have set is : WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"

Comment: Also AllowsTransparency is also set to true ..

Comment: I have a similar issue, but it does go away with Topmost. If Topmost remains true, the taskbar doesn't appear in front of the window.

Answer (score 1):

This will fix it, but I feel there should be a more elegant way:

```
this.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
this.WindowState = this.WindowState != WindowState.Normal 
                 ? WindowState.Normal : WindowState.Maximized;
this.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
```

Btw, I adapted it from this [WinForms answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/507562/60761). So it's not WPF related and you can throw a wider search net.

Comment: When I set the WindowStyle after maximizing, the window overflows the screen by about 8 pixels (appears to be on all sides), rather than maximizing properly.

Answer (score 0):

Setting ResizeMode to NoResize helped on my case:

```
ResizeMode="NoResize"
```