# C# moving window over taskbar

Tags: c#, fullscreen

```
        const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
        int Left = Convert.ToInt32(LeftSizeTextBox.Text);
        int Top = Convert.ToInt32(TopSizeTextBox.Text);
        int Width = Convert.ToInt32(WidthSizeTextBox.Text);
        int Height = Convert.ToInt32(HeightSizeTextBox.Text);
        IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, WindowTextBox.Text);
        SetWindowPos(handle, -2, Top - 8, Left - 30, Width + 32, Height + 38, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        SetForegroundWindow(handle);
```

I want TRUE fullscreen. Currently mine only puts it mostly fullscreen but it stops slightly below the bottom, and doesn't cover the taskbar. How do I made it completely (Windowed borderless) while still being able to alt tab? If you've ever used shiftwindow, that is my desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

To make a (border less) window go **true** fullscreen, go to your Form's properties (CTRL + W, P) then set `ControlBox` to `false` and `WindowState` to `Maximized`. This should display your form over the taskbar. Here is the code of you want to do it dynamically:

```
//ControlBox
this.ControlBox = false;
//WindowState
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

**Edit:** This will only make your form go true fullscreen. Looking at your code I think you are trying to make other forms go fullscreen.

Comment: Correct, I want other windows to go fullscreen

Comment: @Angel I am not sure how to do it with other forms, sorry.

Comment: The answer is missing something, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen