# How to delete control boxes when maximized

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developing an application and I want it to be full screen. As I want to change between different screens, I created a MDIParent and some MDIChilds. But when I say that I want to see it full screen I have this screen:

[image]

I have set properties to:

**Form border style:** None

**Windows state:** Maximized

And I have:

**Maximize box:** False

**Minimize box:** False

**control box:** False

for both MDIParent and MDIChild. But I still have that control box showing...

How can I hide it??

Comment: try this.TopMost = true;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do this by overriding the [Control.CreateParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createparams.aspx) method.

Check out [the Window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600.aspx) that you can apply.

Also check out the [Window Class Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you can apply.

For example (not answering your question but showing you how to change window styles):

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams param = base.CreateParams;
        const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x00020000;
        const int WS_CAPTION    = 0xC00000;
        param.ClassStyle = param.ClassStyle | CS_DROPSHADOW; // Turn on window shadow.
        param.Style = param.Style & ~WS_CAPTION; // Turn off caption.
        return param;
    }
}
```