# Programming full screen/normal screen size button in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, if-statement

I am doing a full screen/normal screen button but the logic suddenly started looping from full screen to normal size each button click and it was working at one point here is a snippet:

```
  If ScreenMode.Text = "Normal Size" Then
        ScreenMode.Text = "Full Size"
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Me.Width = 563
        Me.Height = 447
        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable
        Me.TopMost = False
    ElseIf Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable Then
        ScreenMode.Text = "Normal Size"
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.TopMost = True
    End If
```

Comment: Why do you set ScreenMode.Text = "Full Size" if ScreenMode.Text = "Normal Size"?

Comment: Where's the question ?

Comment: I was experimenting with the if statements to fix the problem but what keeps happening no matter what is both the elif and if statements fully execute when the button is pressed.

Comment: Why is it executing both if and else if statements in the same instance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a WinForms app go Full Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.TopMost = True
    Else
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Me.Width = 563
        Me.Height = 447
        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable
        Me.TopMost = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private isFullScreen As Boolean = False
Private Sub toggleFullScreen()
    isFullScreen = Not isFullScreen
    If isFullScreen Then
        MaximizeBox = False
        MinimizeBox = False
        TopMost = True
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    Else
        MaximizeBox = True
        MinimizeBox = True
        TopMost = False
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    End If
End Sub
```

although i really don't see the difference, must be in your If Statement logic. using a boolean is fine as long as you're not setting fullscreen mode elsewhere manually. but you shouldn't, since you can just call toggleFullScreen().

for some more fun, you can pass a Form ByRef to it, ie:

```
Public Sub toggleFullScreen(ByRef theForm As Form)
If theForm.FormWindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
    With theForm
        .MaximizeBox = False
        .MinimizeBox = False
        .TopMost = True
        .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End With
End If
etc...
```

Comment: The first one is the exact same result.

Comment: well then the question is, what event are you handling that calls the fullscreen function, or what other code catches on size/states changes and alters the window properties... it must be something.

Answer (score -2):

Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
            Me.TopMost = True
        Else
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
            Me.TopMost = False
        End If
    End Sub