# WPF WindowChrome full screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem regarding *WindowChrome*. When I try to go full-screen it does not always go to the task bar. I do not know how it was going to the task bar in order to not be seen at the full-screen task bar.

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:shell="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/shell"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <System:Double x:Key="CaptionShellHeight">5</System:Double>
    <GridLength x:Key="CaptionRowHeight">5</GridLength>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <shell:WindowChrome CaptionHeight="{StaticResource CaptionShellHeight}"
                                    CornerRadius="0"
                                    GlassFrameThickness="0,0,0,1"
                                    NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                                    ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                                    UseAeroCaptionButtons="true"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>

  private void fullscreen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            this.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I apologize for my English I'm from the Netherlands. How to achieve when using fullscreen
WindowChrome shell.

Comment: I want to achieve the same effect as Windows Media Player or Browser based Flash players which take up the ENTIRE (not even the taskbar is visible) real estate when maximised.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a WinForms app go Full Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
WindowChrome.GlassFrameThickness = -1
```