# Setting object attribute to length and width of screen C#

Tags: c#, attributes, width, screen

I am in Visual Studio and am trying to make a Form1 the size of the entire screen. How do I code this, and where do I put it in the code? Or, how could I enter it in the properties?

Comment: A [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen) should help.

Answer (score 0):

In design time you can do it as shown below with red arrow and choosing the `Maximized` option from the dropdown:

[image: Window State of Forms]

In code you can do it like this:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```