# Display App in Full Screen With Windows Taskbar

Tags: c#

[image][image]

I use Window form application and like in the pic the taskbar isn't appear and this is the problem to me
how to can show the task bar
this is the code of two buttons
I want to show the taskbar when the form is maximum

Note: in the first the form will be in the center of screen and minima

```
   private void Button_Restore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
     
        Button_Max.Visible = true;
        Button_Restore.Visible = false;        
    }
    private void Button_Max_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        Button_Restore.Visible = true;
        Button_Max.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you disabled the Maximize button for the form?

Comment: Assign the size of the screen's working area to the Form's `MaximumSize` property.  `this.MaximumSize = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Size;`

Comment: @MattU yes , and I use two buttons for control the size of form

Comment: @dr.null its work! thanks. can you explain to me the code ?

Comment: [Screen.WorkingArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 1):

This will make it "fullscreen" with the taskbar still showing.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
    this.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
    this.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Location;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

have a look to this [How do I make a WinForms app go Full Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen)

Comment: but I also want the form to minimize . and I also see this "have a look to this How do I make a WinForms app go Full Screen" and its don't work

Comment: this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minmized;